# Syntax for AUTOINCREMENT column for MS Access and ODBC

Tags: sql, ms-access, odbc

Using the ODBC JET 4.0 driver with an older (Access 2003 or earlier) MS Access database in C#. The following work:

```
CREATE TABLE [FunkyTable] (FunkyCol INTEGER);
CREATE TABLE [FunkyTable] (FunkyCol INTEGER PRIMARY KEY);
```

But all of the following fails with an error

> ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in CREATE TABLE statement

```
CREATE TABLE [FunkyTable] (FunkyCol INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT);
CREATE TABLE [FunkyTable] (FunkyCol INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT(1,1) PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE [FunkyTable] (FunkyCol INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT);
CREATE TABLE [FunkyTable] (FunkyCol INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT(1,1) PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE [FunkyTable] (FunkyCol INTEGER IDENTITY);
CREATE TABLE [FunkyTable] (FunkyCol INTEGER IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY);
```

What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AUTOINCREMENT` is a field type based on Long Integer, so `INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT` amounts to asking for 2 field types.  However, Access only lets you designate 1 type per field.

Include `PRIMARY KEY` so the field will operate as a proper Access autonumber.  (Without `PRIMARY KEY`, the table would accept duplicate `FunkyCol` values.)

```sql
CREATE TABLE [FunkyTable] (FunkyCol AUTOINCREMENT PRIMARY KEY);
```

Comment: Thanks! To combine with the answer from @PeterG, my tests show that `COUNTER` and `AUTOINCREMENT` both operate in the same way (either with or without `PRIMARY KEY`). Adding `PRIMARY KEY` makes sense.

Comment: Yes, `COUNTER` and `AUTOINCREMENT` are synonyms; either will work the same.

Comment: Does Access and the ODBC JET driver support non-standard incremements? I've tried both `AUTOINCREMENT(5,10)` and `COUNTER(5,10)` which I assumed should "start at 5, and auto-incremement in steps of 10". But both result in "Operation is not supported for this type of object." syntax errors. `AUTOINCREMENT` and `AUTOINCREMENT(1,1)` both work.

Comment: I've set the seed and increment values using ADO/OleDb, but don't know for certain  about ODBC.  My best guess is you can't do it with ODBC.  That's consistent with what Allen Browne said: [The initial seed value and increment value are optional, and can be used only with ADO.](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-49.html#_ftn8)

Comment: Just noticed in your last comment you said `AUTOINCREMENT(1,1)` works.  Sorry I missed that.  Assume you're saying it worked under ODBC, my previous comments were wrong. :-(

Comment: Yes, using the ODBC driver `AUTOINCREMENT` and `AUTOINCREMENT(1,1)` work, but `AUTOINCREMENT(5,10)` does not. I don't think your comment is necesarily wrong! If the comment from Allen Browne is correct, then internally the first two might be synonyms...and the latter a "syntax error". Going to have a go using OleDB and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
CREATE TABLE [FunkyTable] (FunkyCol COUNTER);
```

Found the details in bottom example of this MS documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/create-table-statement-microsoft-access-sql